# AspectJ pointcut pattern for calling to the method on class member with specific annotation

Tags: java, annotations, aspectj

I don't have any experience with AspectJ but recently I've got task to implement and I've read several AspectJ tutorials so I think that AspectJ can be my solution.

The task is the following:
I have a class A with some method b() and objects of this class are included as fields in other classes.
I'd like to annotate these fields with some annotation @C and to get this annotation value each time I call the method b() on field with type A and annotation @C.

Simplified code:

```
   class A{
    field1;
    field2;
    field3;

        void b(String[] fieldsToIgnore){
         doSomething with fields 1,2,3 (excluding fields from fieldsToIgnore array)
    }
        }

   class B{
        @C(value="field1,field2")
        A fieldA;
        }


        //Here when I want to weaver my aspect - before I call to method b() on fieldA with annotation @C - I want to get annotation value and to pass it as an argument to method b()
        new B.fieldA.b()
```

Please help me to write correct pointcut for me advise. I also can't quite understand how can I transfer data from my advise method to my method b() - is it possible at all?

Will appreciate any help - even if you just tell mt "No, it's not possible" - it will save me a lot of time and nerves :)

Comment: Before I answer I want you to clarify: What do you mean by "transfer data from advice to method `b()`"? Please edit the (pseudo) code and show me how you want to use those data in the method. BTW, are you ready to do some manual bookkeeping with regard to the connection of `A` fields and objects assigned to those fields? Because this is what it is going to take - possible, but a little tedious due to your application design.

Comment: I've update my pseudocode. The main idea is that i want to pass list of fields names listed in annotation value to method b(), so that these fields will be ignored during this method execution

Comment: Your call `new B().fieldA.b()` (BTW, you forgot the parentheses there) cannot match the method signature `void b(String[] fieldsToIgnore)` and thus will not compile. This is a Java problem, even before you start using AspectJ. Moreover, your application design is definitely flawed if the application can only work if (a) the application knows about the aspect and cannot work without it and (b) if the aspect needs too know field names which are listed in an annotation as strings and thus will break when refactored. This is no cross-cutting concern and thus no AOP use case even though possible.

Comment: (Continued) Imagine how you would have to convert the strings from the array into fields and get hold of these fields via reflection. It would be slow, ugly and a maintenance nightmare. Please reconsider and describe what the application should do, not how you think it should be implemented. Then I can maybe tell you a clean approach. Are you still a programming beginner, Anna? It seems to be so. No offense meant, I just want to know.

Comment: i totally agree with you about reflection ugliness which will be inflicted by such approach, but on the project i'm working on we already have a lot of reflection used and nobody will refactor all existing code to get rid of it, so it seemed only logical to continue this way.

Comment: in two words about what is it that i'm going to to with these fields: this is a ui selenium tests. we have method which fills all input fields on the page. this method already gets all declared fields in the page class and fills them. now i want to add annotation which would allow me to list fields that should be ignored in this fill method.

Comment: This is going to be a nightmare, but I am going to cook something up for you later when I have some time. Stay tuned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, if you are already using reflection massively anyway - which is not an excuse for not refactoring the code, BTW - and wish to continue doing so, actually you do not really need AspectJ in order to make the mess even worse. You can just do it like this:

**Helper class for reflective field access:**

```java
package de.scrum_master.app;

import java.lang.reflect.Field;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

public class FieldHelper {
  public static Field getField(Class<?> clazz, String fieldName) {
    Field field;
    try {
      field = clazz.getDeclaredField(fieldName);
    } catch (NoSuchFieldException | SecurityException e) {
      throw new RuntimeException("Reflection problem", e);
    }
    field.setAccessible(true);
    return field;
  }

  public static Field[] getFields(Class<?> clazz) {
    Field[] fields = clazz.getDeclaredFields();
    for (Field field : fields)
      field.setAccessible(true);
    return fields;
  }

  public static List<String> extractIgnoredFieldsList(Class<?> clazz, String fieldName) {
    return Arrays.asList(
      getField(clazz, fieldName)
        .getAnnotation(IgnoreFields.class)
        .fieldNames()
    );
  }
}
```

**Marker annotation:**

```java
package de.scrum_master.app;

import java.lang.annotation.ElementType;
import java.lang.annotation.Retention;
import java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy;
import java.lang.annotation.Target;

@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target(ElementType.FIELD)
public @interface IgnoreFields {
  public String[] fieldNames();
}
```

**Class with method to be called:**

```
package de.scrum_master.app;

import java.lang.reflect.Field;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;

import static de.scrum_master.app.FieldHelper.*;

public class A {
  int number = 11;
  String text = "Hi there!";
  Date date = new Date();
  String optionalText = "I am not really always needed";
  int optionalNumber = 123;

  public void doSomething(List<String> ignoredFields) {
    for (Field field : getFields(this.getClass())) {
      if (!ignoredFields.contains(field.getName())) {
        try {
          System.out.println(field.getName() + " = " + field.get(this));
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException | IllegalAccessException e) {
          throw new RuntimeException("Reflection problem", e);
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Class with annotated member fields:**

```
package de.scrum_master.app;

import static de.scrum_master.app.FieldHelper.*;

public class B {
  @IgnoreFields(fieldNames = { "optionalText", "optionalNumber" })
  A noOptionalsA = new A();

  @IgnoreFields(fieldNames = { "text", "number", "date" })
  A onlyOptionalsA = new A();

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    B b = new B();
    b.noOptionalsA.doSomething(extractIgnoredFieldsList(b.getClass(), "noOptionalsA"));
    System.out.println("----------------------------------------");
    b.onlyOptionalsA.doSomething(extractIgnoredFieldsList(b.getClass(), "onlyOptionalsA"));
  }
}
```

**Console log:**

```
number = 11
text = Hi there!
date = Wed Dec 27 18:54:44 ICT 2017
----------------------------------------
optionalText = I am not really always needed
optionalNumber = 123
```

If you do not understand what is happening here or if you still insist in an AspectJ solution, please let me know and I will explain and/or provide extra aspect code.

Comment: thank you for provided solution. I guess i'll use it instead of aspectj because usage of aspectj will give me a lot of headache as we are also using lombok in our project and they don't work well together.

Comment: **Update:** I have refactored the code a bit in order to **(a)** wrap checked reflection-based exceptions into runtime exceptions (i.e. no more need to change method signatures due to reflection usage) and **(b)** move the formerly repeated boilerplate code for getting the ignored field list from the annotation into the helper class.